# GroupBy to count number of overlap substrings in rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dataframe below that I want to compare the sub-strings in rows under GroupBy.

For example, in Project_A, it's to compare Project_A's first row ['William', 'Oliver', 'Elijah', 'Liam'] with Project_A's second row [   'James', 'Mason', 'Elijah', 'Oliver']

Ideal result as:

[image]

I've tried to convert the rows in list, then compare them, but unsuccessful.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np

csvfile = StringIO(
"""
Project Members
Project_A   'William', 'Oliver', 'Elijah', 'Liam'
Project_A   'James', 'Mason', 'Elijah', 'Oliver'
Project_A   'Noah', 'Benjamin', 'Mason', 'William'
Project_A   'Liam', 'Oliver', 'Lucas', 'Elijah'
Project_B   'Oliver', 'Elijah', 'Lucas', 'Liam'
Project_B   'Elijah', 'Benjamin', 'Oliver', 'Liam'
Project_B   'Lucas', 'William', 'James', 'Liam'
Project_C   'Lucas', 'Oliver', 'Mason', 'Elijah'
Project_C   'Mason', 'Elijah', 'William', 'Lucas'
Project_C   'Elijah', 'Oliver', 'Lucas', 'Benjamin'
""")


df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep = '\t', engine='python')


df['Overlaps'] = df.groupby('Project').apply(lambda group: len(set(group['Members'].tolist()) & set(group['Members'].shift(1).tolist()))).tolist()
```

What's the right way to do so?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want to happen with the _different _ projects. Your ideal result isn't showing that. Given that in your "ideal result" you have only project A, I don't see how groupby would apply here.

Comment: Still confusing. I assume you're specifically interested in how many names they have in common?

Comment: @cadolphs, thank you for your comment. yes, how many names in the pair of rows have in common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Pandas approach

```
# encode the unqiue values in Membors as indiator columns
s = df['Members'].str.get_dummies(sep=', ')

# shift the indicators per project and multiply 
# to calculate the intersection with the previous row
overlaps = s * s.groupby(df['Project']).shift(-1)

# Sum along axis 1 to calculate overlap count
df['overlaps'] = overlaps.sum(axis=1)
```

Result

```
     Project                                  Members  overlaps
0  Project_A    'William', 'Oliver', 'Elijah', 'Liam'       2.0
1  Project_A     'James', 'Mason', 'Elijah', 'Oliver'       1.0
2  Project_A   'Noah', 'Benjamin', 'Mason', 'William'       0.0
3  Project_A      'Liam', 'Oliver', 'Lucas', 'Elijah'       0.0
4  Project_B      'Oliver', 'Elijah', 'Lucas', 'Liam'       3.0
5  Project_B   'Elijah', 'Benjamin', 'Oliver', 'Liam'       1.0
6  Project_B      'Lucas', 'William', 'James', 'Liam'       0.0
7  Project_C     'Lucas', 'Oliver', 'Mason', 'Elijah'       3.0
8  Project_C    'Mason', 'Elijah', 'William', 'Lucas'       2.0
9  Project_C  'Elijah', 'Oliver', 'Lucas', 'Benjamin'       0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
df['Members'] = df['Members'].apply(lambda members: [member.strip() for member in members.split(',')])

def overlap_for_series(series):
    return pd.Series([len(set(x[0]).intersection(x[1])) for x in zip(series, series.shift(-1).fillna(''))])

overlaps = df.groupby('Project')['Members'].apply(lambda group: overlap_for_series(group))

print(overlaps)
```

Using list comprehension and some string manipulation to make the list, then using set logic.